# Paypal Business Standard: How to handle action after the payment?

Tags: java, servlets, paypal, payment

I want to use Paypal Payment Standard(the one jumps to paypal to pay and jumps back after payment is done) to handle the payment on my site.

I know I can add a callback url to the button, but I could not figure out the right logic.

I want to store user payment status(true or false) and date into database after they finish checking out and jumping back to my site.

What is the best approach for this? I am thinking some kind of token. I don't know if I am on the right track.

By the way, I use Servlet and JSP in my site.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this payment method on a couple of sites, it is super easy to integrate. On form submission I set a token and call that token back on the confirmation page. I use a receipt page to display the order and then submit it to paypal using a hidden form.

```
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.mysite.com/returnurl.html">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://www.mysite.com/cancelurl.html">
```

You can find all the documentation you need here.

https://merchant.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_formbasics

After a person has paid successfully I call the token into hidden form fields, apply the values add an animated loading image a little javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
setTimeout("document.forms['form1'].submit();",2*1000);
```

data goes to the database and then straight to the thank you success thanks for paying page. Hope this helps.